# Vertically align two divs, with offset?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have two columns of text+graphics. The columns need to be vertically positioned so column 2's top is at the same position as a specific line within column 1. For example,

```
COLUMN 1
line 1.1
line 1.2 <-----> COLUMN 2
line 1.3         line 2.1
line 1.4         line 2.2
...
```

The alignment desired here is column 2 is to start at the same vertical position as line 1.2 (in this example) of column 1. The correct alignment is known at the time the page is composed.

One way to achieve this would be to use a 2-column table, and column 2 has the appropriate number of blank lines at the start (or a calculated top margin), but this seems awkward, and hard to use if some of the lines are graphics instead of text.

Comment: Can you provide code..?

Comment: @ankita patel: There is no code to provide. I was asking how this layout could be accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

1. You can select your `second child` in the first column which I have marked here as red and given a `position:relative`.
2. inside this I have nested the second column with a `position:absolute` which will `always` take the `position` from 1st column second child and given `top:0`
   I hope this will help you.

So, let say you have multiple `li` in your first column and all you want, from your 1st column 3rd child your second column first-child should be inline aligned. So what I made I have opted first column 3rd child using `li:nth-child(3)` and assigned a property called `position: relative` and nested your all 2nd column li inside it( your first column 3rd child ). Now I have assigned `position: absolute` to your 2nd column `li`. When you say position: absolute it will take the position from it's first non-static(eg: relative here) parent which is here your 1st column 3rd child. So it will take the position from the first column 3rd child. Finally given `top:0` which will take 3rd child position and from its top 0.

```css
#wrapper {
  width:700px;
  clear:both;
}
.col1-ul{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
ul.col1-ul > li:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
.col2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
li {
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="col1">
    <ul class="col1-ul">
    <li>COLUMN 1</li>
    <li>line 1.1</li>
    <li>line 1.2
      <div class="col2">
   <ul class="col2-ul">
       <li>COLUMN 2</li>
    <li>line 2.1</li>
    <li>line 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </li>
    <li>line 1.3</li>
    <li>line 1.4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like just what I need. I don't understand, though, how col 2's position is determined. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: he put inside the li div that contains the second col - and set the property -   .col2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

Comment: @Woody20 I have explained the same above (so, let say section) as it is not taking many characters in the comment section. All I have done is I set the column position based in your first column third child. I have explained the same above in the answer section you can have a look if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like two div's that one of them has margin top

```css
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
        .textA {
        float:left;
        }
        .textB {
        float:left;
        margin-top:58px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="textA">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="textB">
        <ul>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
            <li>G</li>
            <li>H</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
</script>
    <style>
 </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although this does approximately the right thing, it depends on knowing exactly what the position of the "alignment" line is (in your example, 58 px). That is not going to work unless we know the characteristics of the font, and the exact size of all graphics preceding the alignment line. And if the user isn't using the same default font, or has overridden it, the spacing will be wrong.

Comment: if you do not know exactly what the height needed you can try calculate it in java script - for example you can measure div height, in Jquery:
$elem.height(); - gives height of the element without padding , border and margin

$elem.innerHeight(); - gives height including padding

$elem.outerHeight(true); - gives height including padding, border and margin

in java script:

element.offsetHeight;
This gives the height of an element